# Has any recent academic research been done on the comparative performance of FOIA response speeds by different European governments?

Tags: government, europe, reference-request, freedom-of-information

Recently, I took part in a large, international investigative journalistic [project](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/mar/22/revealed-ships-may-dump-oil-up-to-3000-times-a-year-in-europes-waters) on dumps of oily waste water by ships. In that context, I did a FOIA (Freedom of Information Act)  request to the Dutch government. Whereas the journalists that partook in the same investigation received the relevant documents pretty quickly in their respective countries when they sent out a similar request, I haven't received the information I asked for even after 8 months and a legal procedure with the administrative judge - who decided in my favour.

The inadequate response from the Dutch government in this case got me wondering about whether any systematic, academic research has been done on the comparative performance of FOIA response speeds by different European countries. I've tried finding recent and relevant scientific literature about this topic on several search engines, but to no avail.

**Question**: are there any academic research papers that compare the response speed and adequateness of FOIA requests in different European countries, preferably including the Netherlands?

*Note*: I've asked the same [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20360/has-any-recent-academic-research-been-done-on-the-comparative-performance-of-foi) on Open Data SE.

Comment: It seems to be a tough question. Let's try to answer it all together. Such research would probably be published in academic journals. So maybe we could start by searching for suitable academic journals and suitable key phrases (EU, open government, ...). It might also be that there simply is no such recent academic research.

Comment: @Trilarion would be great if you could help out! Perhaps it might also be useful to first look at data for separate national countries, and then pull the data together to make comparisons